# Dynamically assign a ID based on date interval for groups

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is an example of a dataset I am working with

```
library(tidyverse)

id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
date <- c("2020-01-01","2020-02-04", "2021-06-08","2022-05-08","2021-08-09","2021-11-29","2020-04-12", "2022-09-12", "2022-09-22")

df <- data.frame(id,date)

# A tibble: 9 × 2
     id date      
  <dbl> <chr>     
1     1 2020-01-01
2     1 2020-02-04
3     1 2021-06-08
4     2 2022-05-08
5     2 2021-08-09
6     2 2021-11-29
7     3 2020-04-12
8     3 2022-09-12
9     4 2022-09-22
```

I would like to group these observations by the ID value and look at the dates to assign another ID based on the days that fall within 90 days of each other like below

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
     id date       ep_id
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 2020-01-01     1
2     1 2020-02-04     1
3     1 2021-06-08     2
4     2 2022-05-08     2
5     2 2021-08-09     1
6     2 2021-11-29     2
7     3 2020-04-12     1
8     3 2022-09-12     2
9     4 2022-09-22     1
```

I can't rack my brain how I would go about this. I would need to be able to add ep_ID from 1:n depending on how many dates fall within 90 days of each other.

Comment: for id 2, i.e 4th row, it can't be 3 as it is the starting of id 2

Comment: Now your 4th row is starting at 2.  Should that be 1?

Comment: dates are out of order, so 'id' 2 first episode is 2021-08-09, and the latest is row 4 which is 2022-05-08 which would fall outside the 90 allowance granting it the episode id of 2

Comment: try the update in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), rn = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ep_id = cumsum(c(1, diff(date) > 90))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(rn) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
     id date       ep_id
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2020-01-01     1
2     1 2020-02-04     1
3     1 2021-06-08     2
4     2 2022-05-08     3
5     2 2021-08-09     1
6     2 2021-11-29     2
7     3 2020-04-12     1
8     3 2022-09-12     2
9     4 2022-09-22     1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I need to buy you a coffee or tea for the amount of questions you've answered for me.